# Como hacer que un li tenga su propio ancho + un ancho fijado (ej. 10px;)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

### Hola a todos!

Quiero hacer que un elemento `<li>` tenga su propio ancho (el que debería de ocupar) + un ancho que le ponga yo. Ejemplo: 10px.

He buscado por internet, pero no he encontrado nada.

Lo que quiero lograr es que tengan cierto tamaño de ancho dependiendo de lo que tenga adentro (ósea un margen uniforme entre los elementos), no un ancho fijo.

(Esto solo pasa en desktop. Vean más abajo para poder reproducir el problema.)

Así es como se ve:
[image: navbar defectuoso]

Aquí el código:

```css
/* Para reproducir el problema, denle click al botón de ejecutar y luego en el de "Página completa" */
.nav {
font-family: 'Inter', arial;
}

.nav li a {
        width: 120px;
        text-align: left;
      }
      
      .nav .button {
        width: 170px;
      }
      
      .lin_logo{
            width:100%;
            display:flex;
      }      

      .nav .nav_togglebars {
             display: none;
         }
         
         .nav  {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: space-between;
          align-items: center;
          background: #0052a3;
          z-index: 1;
      }

      .nav .logo {
          margin: 0 0 0 .45em;
      }
      
      .nav .logo a {
          color: white;
      }

      .nav .logo, .navigation {
          list-style: none;
      }

      .nav .logo a, .navigation a {
          text-decoration: none;
      }

      .nav .navigation  {
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          margin-right: 15px;
          width: auto;
          flex-wrap: nowrap;
          justify-content: space-between;
      }

      .nav .navigation a {
          font-size: 20px;
          display: block;
          flex-wrap: nowrap;
          color: white;
          transition: 0.4s;
          justify-content: space-between;

      }

      .nav .navigation a:hover {
          color: #f0f0f0;
      }
      
      .nav .navigation .button {
          color: white;
          border-radius: 5px;
          padding: 7px;
      }
      
      /* *********** media queries *********** */
      @media all and (max-width: 990px) {
          .nav {
            flex-direction: column;
          }
  
          .nav .logo {
            margin: 0;
          }
  
          .nav .navigation  {
            width: 100%;
            justify-content: space-around;
          }
      }


      /* ****** ****** */
      @media all and (max-width: 600px) {
          .nav .logo {
            margin: .30em 0;
            align-self: left; /* align the logo to the left side of 'flex-container' */
            margin-bottom: 0;
          }
  
          .nav .navigation {
            flex-direction: column;
          }
  
          .nav .navigation a { 
            text-align: center; 
            padding: 8px;
            border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2); 
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
          }
  
          .nav .navigation li:last-of-type a {
            border-bottom: none;
          }
     }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@200;300;400;500&display=swap?ppp" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
<!-- Para reproducir el problema, denle click al botón de ejecutar y luego en el de "Página completa" --->
<div class="nav" style="">
            <div class="lin_logo">
                <h1 class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="logo.svg" style="filter: invert(100%);" width="24%">Logo</a></h1>
                <span class="nav_togglebars"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
            </div>
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>&nbsp;Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="recursos"><i class="fas fa-folder"></i>&nbsp;Recursos</a></li>
                <li><a href="ayuda" style="margin-right: 4px"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i>&nbsp;Ayuda</a></li>
                <li><a class="button" style="background: red;" href="process/cerrarsesion"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>&nbsp;Cerrar sesión</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

> Para reproducir el problema, denle *click* al botón de ejecutar y luego en el de "Página completa"

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* Para reproducir el problema, denle click al botón de ejecutar y luego en el de "Página completa" */
.nav {
font-family: 'Inter', arial;
}

.nav li a {
        width: 120px;
        text-align: left;
      }
      
      .nav .button {
        width: 170px;
      }
      
      .lin_logo{
            width:100%;
            display:flex;
      }      

      .nav .nav_togglebars {
             display: none;
         }
         
         .nav  {
          display: flex;
          padding:10px;
          justify-content: space-between;
          align-items: center;
          background: #0052a3;
          z-index: 1;
      }

      .nav .logo {
          margin: 0 0 0 .45em;
      }
      
      .nav .logo a {
          color: white;
      }

      .nav .logo, .navigation {
          list-style: none;
      }

      .nav .logo a, .navigation a {
          text-decoration: none;
      }

      .nav .navigation  {
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          margin-right: 15px;
          width: auto;
          flex-wrap: nowrap;
          justify-content: space-between;
      }

      .nav .navigation a {
          font-size: 20px;
          flex-wrap: nowrap;
          color: white;
          transition: 0.4s;
          justify-content: space-between;

      }

      .nav .navigation a:hover {
          color: #f0f0f0;
      }
      
      .nav .navigation .button {
          color: white;
          border-radius: 5px;
          padding: 7px;
      }
      
      /* *********** media queries *********** */
      @media all and (max-width: 990px) {
          .nav {
            flex-direction: column;
          }
  
          .nav .logo {
            margin: 0;
          }
  
          .nav .navigation  {
            width: 100%;
            justify-content: space-around;
          }
      }


      /* ****** ****** */
      @media all and (max-width: 600px) {
          .nav .logo {
            margin: .30em 0;
            align-self: left; /* align the logo to the left side of 'flex-container' */
            margin-bottom: 0;
          }
  
          .nav .navigation {
            flex-direction: column;
          }
  
          .nav .navigation a { 
            text-align: center; 
            padding: 8px;
            border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2); 
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
          }
  
          .nav .navigation li:last-of-type a {
            border-bottom: none;
          }
     }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@200;300;400;500&display=swap?ppp" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
        <!-- Para reproducir el problema, denle click al botón de ejecutar y luego en el de "Página completa" --->
<div class="nav" style="">
            <div class="lin_logo">
                <h1 class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="logo.svg" style="filter: invert(100%);" width="24%">Logo</a></h1>
                <span class="nav_togglebars"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
            </div>
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>&nbsp;Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="recursos"><i class="fas fa-folder"></i>&nbsp;Recursos</a></li>
                <li><a href="ayuda"*texto en itálica*><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i>&nbsp;Ayuda</a></li>
                <li><a class="button" style="background: red;" href="process/cerrarsesion"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>&nbsp;Cerrar sesión</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hola, no se si es lo que buscabas.

Comment: Los elementos se colapsan :(. Por cierto, revisa [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: y que hace esto? cual era el error? como lo solucionas?

Comment: @Christian El detalle es que tienes en los estilos en la parte `.nav .navigation a {}` asignado el display en tipo block, igual para dispositivos mas pequeños debes de utilizar las media querys, saludos.

Comment: Eso lo debes explicarles en tu respuestas, si solo muestras el código nadie entiende nada